# Google Apps Script Web App javascript Origin invalid

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hello knowledgeable people!

I am trying to make my first web app using Google Apps Script. I would like to use the google sign in system which I have partially setup. I have created the button and have included the relevant scripts but I don't understand what to do with the Authorised JavaScript origins. I have built the app in the Google Apps Script platform and have published the web app and have the published URL but this URL is invalid for the javascript origin as it has a path. I have tried just putting in the https://script.google.com but this doesn't work.  I plan to embed the webapp in a google sites website but that has a path too. Could someone please explain what the javascript origin is and where I can find it? I apologise if this is a stupid question, I am a beginner after all!

Many thanks

Comment: Read the linked question above your post. If you still have questions, let me know or ask a new question with your research.

Comment: Thank you so much... I am sorry to have wasted your time when it was already answered elsewhere!